# The C Programming K&R Exercise 1-11

Tags: c

I'm currently coming thru Word Counting program . And i got a tricky Exercise.
I can't understand what exactly this exercise want me to do .

Here the Exercise itself
**Revise the word counting program to use better definition of "word," for example, a sequence of letters,digits and apostrophes that begins with a letter**

I cant get what it actually want .It want me to count symbols digits apostrophes or ether it want me to put names for all those symbols digits etc. like "word," - will be `A(") word comma(,) A(")`
or there something else.

This is the program which counts lines, characters, and new lines

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YES 1
#define NO 0

main ()
{
    // CTRL+Z will Signal to EOF-End of File 
    int c,nl,nw,nc,inword;  //nl -new line
                            //nw -new word
                            //nc -new chatacter
                            //inword -program in word or not

    inword=NO;
    nl=nw=nc=0;
    while ((c=getchar()) !=EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
            inword=NO;
        else if (inword==NO)
        {
            inword=YES;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl,nw,nc);

    getchar(); 
}
```

Can you guys explain to me what actually the Exercise want me to do?  I don't need already complete code. Iwant to go thru the coding myself. I just don't get what i actually need to do here in Exercise.

Comment: Have you looked at the word counting program that it mentions?

Comment: it wants you to improve the definition of a word with respect to the previous exercise. For example you can use a dictionary to match actual words, or ignore the words that are less then 3 characters, or ignore words with digits, whatever.

Comment: It is thinking that you probably should count `a+b` (no spaces) as 2 words rather than 1 (or maybe as 0 since it doesn't consist of just letters, digits and apostrophes), or `a + b` (with spaces) as 2 words rather than 3.  You might want to think about hyphens as well as apostrophes.

Comment: Thanks Guys  will try out those ways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program you posted treats everything which is delimited by whitespace as a word. So these are all words: `12` `a,b123456` `2-3@!#`.

It asks you to improve the program with a better definition of word, and gives an example: "a sequence of letters,digits and apostrophes that begins with a letter".

So with this example `John's` and `a123` is a word, but `12`, `1a` and `a-b` aren't.

Comment: To clarify, "a-b" should probably be 2 words (a la "post-processing").